# android: collapsing toolbar bounces on scroll up

Tags: android, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have the following layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp">

         <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                <RelativeLayout 
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/layout_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" 
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <com.android.volley.toolbox.VolleyImageView 
                            android:id="@+id/image_toolbar"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                        .... some text views aligned over image...
                </RelativeLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_brands"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When i scroll up fast in recycler view the collapsed toolbar doesn't open smoothly but bounces and gets closed. I don't know whats wrong. I am following [this](http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/) article.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Updating to v23 design and v23 recyclerview seems to fix the bounce effect. You need to change compileSdkVersion to 23 and buildToolsVersion to "23.0.0" as well.
Be aware v23 have other bugs such as crash if you try to scroll from the header

```
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout.java:449)
```

Different solutions for this new bug here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183166

This is a bug tracked on google and they said it is supposed to be fixed in com.android.support.design v23

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175243

Comment: It does not seem to be fixed as I am experiencing the same issue and also the newest version of the Google IO App have this problem.